# Swift 4 UIView.Animate not firing and ignores animation

Tags: swift

The following code works great in all my viewControllers except 1.
The purpose of the code is to animate an arrow from left to right into the view while fading alpha up to 1.0. arrowImage is UIImageView which is connected via an outlet on the storyboard. Can anyone tell me why this viewController does not run the animation? I'm using latest Xcode and iOS 11.4. Thanks in advance.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.arrowImage.alpha = 0.0
    self.arrowImage.frame = CGRect(x: 1200, y: 412, width: 809, height: 236)


    if self.arrowImage.alpha == 0.0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 20.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8,  options: .curveEaseIn, animations:
            {
                // self.startButton.center = CGPoint(x:607 + 759/2 ,y:265)
                self.arrowImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 412, width: 809, height: 236)
                self.arrowImage.alpha = 1.0
        })


    }
```

Comment: What happens when you move this into didAppear ?

Comment: Are you using constraints to set the position of your view?

Comment: I tried same code it worked at my end with Animation, Try using animation block in **DispatchQueue.main.async { /// Animation code }**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the image view has AutoLayout constraints on it, and after viewDidLoad the view controller's content view gets resized for the current display size, and the constraints are applied. That will cause your frame changes to be ignored.

I would expect the alpha animation to still work, so your image view should animate into visibility over a 20 second period (so **very** slowly.)

If that doesn't happen I would suggest setting the arrowImage.alpha to 1.0 without any animation and make sure it appears. If it still doesn't appear then something else is wrong and you'll have to go figure that out.

You should move your animation code to viewDidAppear as BonanzaDriver suggests, and you should create an IBOutlet to an x position AutoLayout constraint and animate that constraint's constant in your animation rather than trying to animate the frame (since AutoLayout often overrides changes to your explicit frame/bounds settings.)

Comment: Thanks. I moved it to viewDidAppear and all is well. I learned this lesson in Objective C and I guess I just learned it again in Swift.

Comment: is there any way to animate only to the objects x ? Could someone post an example? Thanks.

Comment: As described in my answer, you can add an outlet to a (x position) constraint, and animate changing the constraint's constant value (you change the constraint's constant and put the code `view.layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block.)