# UIView.animate not animating on one function

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have two functions that animates a `UIView`. One is for showing it and the other is for dismissing the view. What's weird is the animation for showing the view is working but the one for dismissing isn't.

`show()` is being called right after the view has been added as a subview.

```
func show() {
    self.viewContainer.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height + 500
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.viewContainer.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

While `dismiss()` is called using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` or a button press.

```
func dismiss() {
    self.overlay.isHidden = true
    self.viewContainer.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.viewContainer.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height + 500
    }) { (_) in
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by animating the bottom constraint of the view instead of its frame.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = -500
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { (_) in
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Got a hint out of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378252/9629494

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
func dismiss() {
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
     self.viewContainer.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height + 500
     self.overlay.isHidden = true
 }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it's still not animating

Comment: didn't work. I've also tried putting it inside DispatchQueue.main.async but it still dismisses without animation

Comment: Okay, @DavidMempin check above and note that you are animating something and hiding something else

Comment: removing the self.view.removeFromSuperview() won't help since I need the subview removed right after the animation.

Comment: add it then and give it a try @DavidMempin

Answer (score 0):

remove this code in dissmis()

```
self.viewContainer.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
```

Why are you doing this in show()?

```
self.viewContainer.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
```

If you wanted to show in center use

```
self.viewContainer.center.y = self.view.center.y
```